# Solve Diophantine equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation

What is the best way to solve Diophantine equation like this `x^2 – x*y – 2*y^2 = 7` in Matlab? In this particular case, the answers should be `(3; –2), (5; 2), (–3; 2), (–5; –2)`.

Comment: See [this File Exchange submission](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56143-diophantine-equation-solver). If you have the Symbolic Math toolbox, you can also use MuPAD from with Matlab to [solve Diophantines](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/solve.html#diophantine): `evalin(symengine,'solve(x^2-x*y-2*y^2=7,[x,y],Domain=Z_)')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can brute force it, although I am sure there are better algebraic ways:

```
x = -5:5;
y = -5:5;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
f = X.^2-X.*Y-2*Y.^2;

[X(f==7),Y(f==7)]
```

you can sweep `x` and `y` between the desired regions. It will also work for decimal values `x = -5:0.01:5;`.